# Доступ к private структуре класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Вопрос: как правильно осуществить доступ к полям структуры?

```
class A {
  private:

     struct B
     {
        std::string W;
     };

     B D[100];

  public:
     A(){};
     void addW(std::string W);
};
```

Comment: Поясните вопрос подробнее, в чем состоит проблема?

Comment: Где то так внутри addW `D[index].W = W;`. Обилие верхнего регистра смущает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
class A {
private:
    struct B
    {
        std::string W;
    };
    B D[100];
    int last = 0;
public:
    A(){};
    void addW(std::string W)
    {
        if (last == 100) throw exception("Выход за пределы диапазона")
        D[last++].W = W;
    }
};
```

Внутри класса вы можете делать с `private` все, что хотите. Если вопрос о том, как обратиться к ней извне - то, например, так:

```
public:
    A(){};
    void addW(std::string W)
    {
        D[last++].W = W;
    }
    std::string get(int index) const
    {
        // Проверка индекса на корректность
        return D[index].W;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит рассмотреть использование контейнера `std::vector`?

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
private:
  struct structB
  {
    std::string field;
  };

  std::vector<structB> arrayOfB;

public:
  A() {};
  void addString(const std::string& str)
  {
    structB appenededB;
    appendedB.field = str;
    arrayOfB.push_back(appendedB);
  }
};
```